# What is up with this wierd BSON date saving?

Tags: mongodb, bson

I'm currently writing a driver for MongoDB, so I have to dig a little deeper and so I find this:

BSON spec for DateTimeUTC:

`"\x09" e_name int64`

BSON spec for int64:

`"\x12" e_name int64`

BSON spec for timeStamp (although I know its almost always used internally, its just to show BSON makes use of unsigned integers):

`"\x11" e_name uint64`

It seems a bit controversial to me. Why are int64 and utc millis even separated? Does mongoDB use different ways to compare different BSON dateTimeUTCs?

And why is dateTimeUTC NOT a uint64 but a signed integer? millis are always > 0. Is there a reason behind this? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DateTimeUTC is used to represent a point in time. It predates BSON, and has historically been using signed integer. This is to enable the use of DateTimeUTC to point to a date *before* the epoch. Otherwise, it won't be possible to represent dates before 1970-01-01 using DateTimeUTC.

In contrast, timestamp is for mostly internal use, and is expected to be used for mostly current dates that have little need to represent a time before the epoch (e.g. the timestamp of an operation).

There's a related question in UNIX StackExchange regarding this: [Why does Unix store timestamps in a signed integer?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25361/why-does-unix-store-timestamps-in-a-signed-integer)

Comment: perhaps you could answer this too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58660955/why-the-trailing-0x00-byte-after-string